# Find music by key (musical scale, like F major, D minor...)

Tags: music

Many times I'm in a mood to listen only to music or songs that are in a particular key of a musical scale, for example F major, D minor, etc..

Is there anything to help me find music that is composed in a particular key?

Comment: Do you mean find music in your local collection or find music on the Internet ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor good question. Originally I meant in my local collection. But I'd be just as interested to find something on the internet.

Comment: There are sites that let you search for a song by mood such http://www.allmusic.com/moods, but not by the actual key. But there are ways to find the key of songs you have in our local collection as I describe in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AcousticBrainz](http://acousticbrainz.org) is a crowdsourcing site that allows uses to do acoustic analysis of their songs and then upload the results to be shared. The songs should first be matched to a [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org) recording so that the song is correctly identified. As part of the acoustic analysis it tries to identify the main key of the song amongst other attributes such as BPM and moods. So far about two million unique song have been analysed.

**Disclaimer:I am SongKong developer**

[SongKong Pro](http://www.jthink.net/songkong) is music tagger software that you can can use to both match your songs to MusicBrainz and use the AcousticBrainz analysis to determine additional features of your songs such as the key scale. This is then stored within the file itself using standard metadata standards so it can be used by other music applications.

[image]